# select only one checkbox and add class for the checked input

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a list of checkbox and want to select the only one check box and add the class for the checkbox input and select another checkbox remove that class from the existing checkbox

```
 $('input.myclass').click(function () 
  {
        var id =  $(this).attr('id').replace('image-','');
        $('input.myclass:checked').not(this).removeAttr('checked');

        var sFilter = "";
        $('input.myclass[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
            sFilter = sFilter + (this.checked ? $(this).val() : "");
        });
    check();    
    });

    function check(){
    var a = $('input:checkbox[name=cover_image]:checked').val();
    alert(a);
    }
```

I want to select only one checkbox and class for the checked checkbox if that checkbox not checked then remove the class for that

Comment: Since you only want to select one, wouldn't radio buttons be more appropriate?

Comment: I want to select only one checkbox and class for the checked checkbox if that checkbox not checked then remove the class for that

Comment: Users expect certain behaviors for different types of input.  You should use `radio` buttons if you want to only allow one choice.  Over-riding the expected and default behavior of checkboxes will only confuse and frustrate your user.

Comment: Just use CSS, no script required.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use checkboxes(and not radio buttons) for some reason, do something like this:

```
$('input:checkbox').on('click', function () {
    $('input.selected').removeClass('selected').prop('checked', false);
    $('input:checked').addClass('selected');
});
```

Edit: Removing the attribute works, but property manipulation is a slighty better way of doing it(as suggested by RobG)

Comment: Adding and removing the checked attribute does not check or uncheck a checkbox, it sets whether or not the checkbox is checked by default (at least it does in versions of jQuery that distinguish between attributes and properties).

Comment: @RobG I'm using jQuery 1.10.2 with Chrome V32, and it's unchecking the box when I do removeAttr('checked'). It's even checking the box with attr('checked', true). The only odd thing is that it doesn't check the box with that code once you uncheck it using removeAttr

Answer (score 1):

you may use `on()` to listen the changes on group of checkboxes.

```
var $checkBoxes = $(":checkbox").on("change", function () { // Here listening the changes on checkbox using on()
  $checkBoxes.removeClass("change").attr("checked", false); // remove the class from existing Checkbox
  $(this).addClass("change").attr("checked", true); // adding the class for the currenly checked checkbox
});
```

working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Kug4C/2/) is here

Answer (score 1):

For your purpose first remove classes from all checkbox and unchecked them and then add class to clicked checkbox and checked it as below

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function () {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").removeClass('selected').attr('checked', false);
    $(this).addClass('selected').attr('checked', true);
});
```

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E3EFz/) for your question